# Why does Mechanize login keep failing?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to login to a class site, but every time I submit the form I get the login page.

I have used both ways to submit the form both resulting in the same outcome. I've printed out the form before submitting it to check and make sure all values are filled in correctly which they were. Any suggestions on why this could be failing?

```
#!/home/webadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

passwd = gets.chomp

a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
   agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
   agent.log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end

page = a.get('https://it210.it.et.byu.edu/accounts/login/?next=/')
puts "\n=== Login Page ==="
pp page
form = page.forms.first
form['username'] = 'user'
form['password'] = passwd
#pp form
page = a.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
#page = form.submit

puts "\n\n\n=== Next Page (should be homepage) ==="
pp page
```

Comment: It's 2.1 and I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 as you can probably see in the script lol.

Comment: 2.1 is too buggy to use IMHO. I would try 1.0.0

Comment: Yeah I heard that, tried 2.0.1 1.0.0 all with the same problem. This is funky don't know why it's doing it.

Comment: The only thing to do is proxy through fiddler or charles so you can compare your request to a real browser request.

Comment: It's ok I gave up on Ruby and decided to do it in perl (took 15 mins to do what I wanted). It's nice having so many languages to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem. This worked for me

```
$browser.get("something")
login_page = $browser.page.links.find { |l| l.text == 'Login' }.click

username_field = login_page.form.field_with(:name => "username")
username_field.value = $username
password_field = login_page.form.field_with(:name => "password")
password_field.value = $password

login_page.form.submit
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm going directly to the login page with get() so I don't need the extra line to click the login page. The form is filled out correctly as well it's just a problem with submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
 
`page = a.submit(form, form.buttons.first)`

try
`page = form.click_button`